# MS Excel VBA userform: conditional combobox list based on multiple tables from MS Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, combobox

I am working on Excel application with connection to MS Access database. 
My Excel Workbook contains GUI with multiple userforms to enter and exchange the data between different tables in MS Access database.

In one of those userforms I have couple of comboboxes which are filled out based on the values from different tables. The problem starts when I want to populate combobox considering values chosen already in other comboboxes.

---

To explain clearly, here is a description of exact configuration of database and userform:

**MS Access database:**
There are two tables:

**Table 1:** Columns: materials, parameters

**Table 2:** Columns: material property, parameters1, parameters2, parameters3...

---

**MS Excel userform:**
There are three comboboxes:

**ComboBox1:** material (based on list from Column1 in Table1)

**ComboBox2:** material property (based on list from column1 in Table2). One property appears couple of times. There are few other factors.

**ComboBox3:** (problematic one): There should be a list of parameters based on the material, and property chosen. Combobox1 determines which column from Table2 should be taken into account, and Combobox2 determines which rows should be listed in Combobox3 - same property appears couple of times, therefore that will be a list.

---

Below little illustration to visualize:

[image]

---

Could you please help me to find proper VBA code to list required records?

EDIT:
The code I used to populate first two ComboBoxes:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbPath
Dim i As Integer

dbPath = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Material] FROM Table1 ORDER BY [Material];", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
rst.MoveFirst

With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rst![Material]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With

rst.Close

rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Property] FROM Table1 ORDER BY [Property];", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
rst.MoveFirst

With Me.ComboBox2
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rst![Property]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With

rst.Close

UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this all in Access? The forms are *much* easier to work with, and it be all-around much easier in the end, for you and the users.

Comment: What code do yo use to populate your comboboxes? What code have you tried until now for combobox 3?

Comment: @ ashleedawg, The reason why I am using excel to enter records in MS Access database is that other users don't have a licence for MS Office Professional package. Nevertheless I would like to make it possible, so I found this solution quite useful for simple design.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns. Until now I have configured only two comboboxes and I'm empty of ideas now. I will edit my post  in a moment with a code I used for first two...

Comment: About licensing, Google for **ACCESS RUNTIME** (https://www.microsoft.com/en-uS/download/details.aspx?id=50040). It's a free download so people can use Access Databases. This complement does not allo to design in Access, but users can manage databases designed by others (you).

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: Ouch! I didn't know about it. I am a very beginner with MS Access, and actually it's my first contact with a database. That's a pity, because I've already designed menu and userforms in Excel..

Comment: Well worth your while to redesign in Access. I inherited a partially complete db setup with Excel as user interface for input/output. After dealing with it for 3 months, scrapped the Excel component and built all forms and reports in Access. Added 6 months to the project but it was worth it. I had a LOT of forms and reports to rebuild. Hopefully won't be same in your case.